# JS Slider with demo failing with no apparent error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built (or am trying to build) a responsive slider but I am seeing something strange i.e nothing working? The console tells me there is an unexpected token on line 55 which is the first line of the following:

```
$.each($slides.function(index){
        // Create a button element for the button
        var $button = $('<button type="button" class="slide-btn">&bull;</button>');
        if (index === currentIndex) {
            $button.addClass('active');
        }
        $button.on('click', function(){
            move(index);
        }).appendTo('.slide-buttons');
        buttonArray.push($button);
    });
```

Line 55 is stating that that the invalid token s the `{` after the `function(index)` I have created a demo which is all of the code I have put together thus far. I am wondering if somebody could cast an eye on why this isn't building out and why I am getting this error as I have counted the parenthesis and curly braces?

[Demo of the slider build](https://jsfiddle.net/evLLwwg8/)

Comment: It sounds like you want: `$.each($slides, function(index){...});` a comma, not a dot. FYI, you could instead use: `$slides.each(function(index){...});` which is the recommanded way to iterate through a jq matched set (keeping chaining)

Comment: Crikey such a rookie error - strange thing is even wen fixing that the slide isn't showing the nav buttons or even sliding? I am clearly missing something here?

Comment: There is many things wrong with the jsFiddle you have posted. `advance()` method is defined inside a each loop function scope,  you didn't included jQuery and maybe more... So ask new question once you encounter other issue, don't expect someone else to fix your complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well for  a start you attach the JQuery like this:

```
$('.slider').each(function(){
```

but there isn't a single element in the mark-up that you posted that has

```
class='slider'
```

So the JQuery in question doesn't match a single element in you mark-up and so the code just doesn't run and you get no buttons.

Also your code (pushes buttons) into button array using

```
buttonArray.push($button);
```

but at no point to it add the contents of tbe button to the DOM so they're not going to show up even if your code had run.

YOU are missing the var in front of the variable declarations

```
 var $this          = $(this),
```

You don't reference JQuery even though you're using it.

@A. Wolff is also right about the '.' instead of the comma and that there are a number of other error in the mark up that you put together

Taking purely what you had and not even attempting to fix any bugs in the code, just the syntax issues, thne following moves images around and does something. (You can sort that the logic bugs in your code yourself)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .slider { position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;}
      .slide-group{ width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;}
      .slide{ width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none; position: absolute;}
      .slide:first-child{ display: block;}    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-group">
        <div class="slide slide-1"><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="slide slide-2"><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg" /><div class="slide slide-2">
        <div class="slide slide-3"><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg" /><div class="slide slide-3">
        <div class="slide slide-4"><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg" /><div class="slide slide-4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-buttons"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.slider').each(function(){
          var $this = $(this),
              $group = $this.find('.slide-group'),
              $slides = $this.find('.slide'),
              buttonArray = [],
              currentIndex  = 0,
              timeout;

          function move(newIndex) {
            var animateLeft, slideLeft;
            advance();
            if ($group.is(':animated') || currentIndex === newIndex) {
              return;
            }
            buttonArray[currentIndex].removeClass('active');
            buttonArray[newIndex].addClass('active');

            if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
              slideLeft = '100%';
              animateLeft = '-100%';
            } else {
              slideLeft = '-100%';
              animateLeft = '100%';
            }
            $slides.eq(newIndex).css( {left: slideLeft, display: 'block'} );
            $group.animate( {left:animateLeft} , function() {
              $slides.eq(currentIndex).css( {display: 'none'} );
              $slides.css( {left:0} );
              currentIndex = newIndex;
            });
          }
          function advance() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
              if (currentIndex < ($slides.length - 1)) {
                move (currentIndex + 1);
              } else {
                move(0);
              }
            }, 4000);
          }
          $.each( $slides, function(index) {
            // Create a button element for the button
            var $button = $('<button type="button" class="slide-btn">&bull;</button>');
            if (index === currentIndex) {
              $button.addClass('active');
            }
            $button.on('click', function(){
              move(index);
            }).appendTo('.slide-buttons');

            buttonArray.push($button);
          });
          advance();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```